# Photoshop CC 2019 not generating all frames in Video Timeline animation

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been experiencing some issues with Photoshop animation lately. When i open the Video Timeline and begin animating (setting keyframes, moving layers, transforming layers, etc.) at 30FPS it only renders around a 3rd of the frames.

Example:

I need to make a animation that is 15 frames long. I animate it how I want and view the preview playback. While looking at the playback I can see that the playhead is moving on all the 15 frames but the subject is only moving every 3rd frame.

Video link to example here: [All frames not rendered. - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqJZ1YjwrUs&feature=youtu.be)

What I've tried:

- Retting all setting to default.
- Reinstalling Photoshop.

This issue wasn't there before and I've been animating for months now without problems...

Comment: hello and welcome to GDSE. can you tell us which resolution (px? or cm doesnt matter just tell us the canvas size) you are animating?

Comment: Thank you. Canvas res is 112x112 px.

Comment: found out problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is photoshop doesn't do subpixel transformation**

first of all thanks @sergey for suggesting changes.

as photoshop is limited for zooming out stuff because of pixel characteristic so when you do very small changes in transform like 10 pixel in 2 second then it will change only 5 pixel in 1 second means if your fps is 30 then your 6 keyframes will be exact same and 7th keyframe will be different. the only possible solution i think and tried is tweaking resolution.

=> assume your resolution is 112x112; and to reproduce smooth animation i did following step.

=>Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+I</kbd> to open Image Size popup and change your resolution to the power of 2 as @Sergey suggested (don't worry photoshop won't hang since this issue will only triggered when your resolution is very low) so it'll make your canvas 896*896 and now all out your keyframes will behave properly

=> once your animation complete press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S</kbd> or do save for web and then there before saving you can resize your output to 10%

Hope it helps!

-Regards ; Design Phoenix

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I have time.

Comment: Actually the problem is that Photoshop doesn't do subpixel transformations: Animate (ex Flash) or AfterEffects would do the same animation without pixel jumps. Also you probably should mention that the file should be resized up using the Nearest Neighbour sampling method and in power of two (x4-8, not 10) to conserve hard pixel edges and resized down using the Bilinear sampling method: otherwise the result will be blurry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This fixed my problem! Thanks! :)